# Stereo-Processing, Census Based

Tags: image-processing

Hi I'm currently trying to implement a stereo matching algorithm in c and I'm having trouble to understand a part in the
[paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a11e/deab7232649cd7e16fe23cb17830bfcf121e.pdf).

My Problem is the part after the subpixel calculation on page 17. I don't understand it how to get the subpixel disparity map for both directions. Also I'm a little bit confused if my cost aggregation is correct. It's recommended to use a 5x5 windows and sum the values over this block. Do I sum all values in this 5x5 block or do I add every second in every second row, like I did for the census transformation? Thanks for the help!